# Python underscore as a function parameter

Tags: python, parameters, identifier, metasyntactic-variable

I have a python specific question. What does a single underscore `_` as a parameter means?
I have a function calling `hexdump(_)`. The _ was never defined, so I guess it has some special value, I could not find a reference telling me what it means on the net. I would be happy if you could tell me.

Comment: To people answering this: what does a single underscore as a parameter mean in ("normal") python **code**, *and **not** when used in the interpreter*?

Answer (score 21):

From what I've been able to figure out, it seems like this is the case:

`_` is used to indicate that the input variable is a *throwaway variable/parameter* and thus might be required or expected, but will *not* be used in the code following it.

For example:

```
# Ignore a value of specific location/index 
for _ in range(10) 
    print("Test")
  
# Ignore a value when unpacking 
a,b,_,_ = my_method(var1)
```

(Credit to [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/underscore-_-python/))

The specific example I came across was this:

```
    def f(_):
        x = random() * 2 - 1
        y = random() * 2 - 1
        return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 < 1 else 0
```

Comment: amazing how I came here for the exact same example (found in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi.py) haha

Comment: Or, as in [this example](https://medium.com/the-dl/how-to-use-pytorch-hooks-5041d777f904), you can do this for a second throway variable by using a double underscore.

Answer (score 13):

In Python shells, the underscore (`_`) means the result of the last evaluated expression in the shell:

```
>>> 2+3
5
>>> _
5
```

There's also `_2`, `_3` and so on in IPython but not in the original Python interpreter. It has no special meaning in Python source code as far as I know, so I guess it is defined somewhere in your code if it runs without errors.

Comment: Why do you think this is not answering the question? In my opinion, it does.

Comment: `What does a single underscore _ as a parameter means?`  - underscore as a function parameter, not as a statement (in interactive interpreter)

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik It's still a variable, even if it's the entire expression serving as an expression statement. (Also, the original question asks about an *argument* to a function, despite using the word parameter.)

Answer (score 10):

underscore is considered a 'don't care' variable, furthermore IDEs like PyCharm will not give a warning for it if it is unused

so in a function

```
def q(a, b, _, c):
    pass
```

the IDE will underline a,b and c (unused parameter) but not the underscore

why would you use it and not omit the parameter?

->when you inherit from some class and want to override a function where you don't want to use some parameter

other common use is to indicate you don't want to use a part of a tuple when you iterate (or other unpacking) - this reduces clutter

```
names_and_food = [('michael', 'fruit'), ('eva', 'vegetables')]
for name, _ in names_and_food:
    print(name)
```

I cant find it in any python PEP, but pylint has it even in the [FAQ](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/faq.html#i-have-a-callback-function-where-i-have-no-control-over-received-arguments-how-do-i-avoid-getting-unused-argument-warnings)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have a special value in the code you write. It stores the result of the last expression you evaluated in your interactive interpreter and is used for convenience

Comment: The interpreter you get when you type `python` at the prompt and hit enter. Try typing `3+4` enter at the `>>>` prompt and hitting enter. Then trying printing the value of `_`. You'll get `7` (result of last expression evaluated).