# Python - "_" Argument to functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I have seen this several times:

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [(x,y) for x in nums for y in nums]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]
>>> min(_, key=lambda pair: pair[0]/pair[1])
(1, 5)
```

In the code above what is the purpose of: the "_" in the min function and where else can it be used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787277/python-underscore-as-a-function-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python underscore as a function parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787277/python-underscore-as-a-function-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the interactive interpreter _ is used to reference the last returned value.

Eg

```
>>> 2 + 4
6
>>> _ + 4
10
```

So you can use it as an argument in a function as well

```
>>> 2 + 4
6
>>> for i in range(_): print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
5
```